# Git track only in local copy

Tags: git

I have a remote repository in a server location. I am keeping local copies in two machines. In the code, there are file paths that are machine specific. I would like to keep one local copy sync with the remote and another just ignore changes. Am I able to do that ? 
I can remove the file from versioning system, however, is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: So it seems file f is in the remote repo. On a cloned version C1 you want to keep it in sync with the remote repo. On a cloned version C2 you do not  want to sync f but keep everything else synced. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged MYLOCAL.CFG
```

so, that on commit, changes to the file will be ignored

but 
    git pull origin

will complain that MYLOCAL.CFG is going to be changed so you have to manually save and restore.

```
copy MYLOCAL.CFG MYLOCAL_SAVE.CFG
git checkout -f MYLOCAL.CFG
git PULL 
copy MYLOCAL_SAVE.CFG MYLOCAL.CFG
git update-index --assume-unchanged MYLOCAL.CFG
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a user.config file which would include any of the file paths or machine specific variables which would overrid the web.config or other config files. Then you would add the user.config file to the .gitignore.

Comment: I see, separating machine specific part from the common file.